# More than one string required to match on, a better way?

Tags: c#

I am just looking if there is a better way to do the following.

Say I have the following strings:

```
string fooWeb = "web";
string fooDesktop = "desktop";
string fooMac = "mac";
string fooIphone = "iphone";
string fooAndroid = "android";


list<string> Names = new List<string>();
Names.Add("web");
Names.Add("mac");
Names.Add("iphone");
Names.Add("android");
```

I am looping through this list and i want to exclude the item which contains for example "web" & "mac" & and "android" there could be others too.

Is there a better way to achieve this than what I am trying below:

```
foreach (var item in this._repo.FooRepo())
if (!(item.SystemName == "Web" || item.SystemName == "android" || item.SystemName == "mac"))
{
  //add to new list
}
}
```

I am asking, as I have around 8 strings to check against.

Comment: Would a regular expression work?

Comment: better in what sense? better so that you don't need to list all the cases or that you want to have shorter code? For the latter you could use LINQ: `var list = this._repo.FooRepo().Except(new List<string> { "Web", "android", "mac"});` but this creates additional list object which is not really needed.

Comment: I guess the latter as it seems cumbersum to write all these out in the if statement, all the answers below are valid suggestions. I prefer this linq with .Except. I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could through them into an array and use the `.Contains()` method.

```
var validItems = new [] { "Web", "android", "mac" };

foreach (var item in this._repo.FooRepo())
{
    if (!validItems.Contains(item))
    {
        //add to new list
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but also wouldn't I need to do that for each string?

Comment: You would just add the string to the array. If you have a set of valid data, you are going to need that persisted somewhere. That could be hardcoded into the array, in a database, in a config file, or some other way.

Comment: thanks, i will take your points on board :)

Comment: I will accept this, as this seems appropriate for my scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

First part simplified:

```
list<string> Names = new List<string> () {
    "web",
    "mac",
    "iphone",
    "android"
};
```

or:

```
var Names = new [] {
    "web",
    "mac",
    "iphone",
    "android"
};
```

or:

```
string[] Names = new string[] {
    "web",
    "mac",
    "iphone",
    "android"
};
```

Second part simplified:

```
myList.Add(this._repo.FooRepo().Where(i => !Names.Contains(i.SystemName)));
```

Comment: thank you for your input :)

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own method to evaluate any number of strings, which can be used whenever - in a separate, static class:

```
public static class StringFunctions
{
    public static bool IfContains(this string inString, params string[] comparisonStrings)
    {
        return comparisonStrings.Contains(inString);
    }
}
```

This can be called like so

```
if(!item.SystemName.IfContains("web", "desktop", "mac", "iphone", "android"))
{
    //add to new list
}
```

You can also pass an array into the method

```
string[] words = { "web", "desktop", "mac", "iphone", "android" };
if(!item.SystemName.IfContains(words))
{
    //add to new list
}
```

Comment: thank you for your input, this is how i would have done it. but i guess I was searching for a shorter way of doing it.

Comment: Your first method could be simplified to simply 1 line: `return comparisonStrings.Contains(inString);`

Comment: @maksymiuk of course, I was not thinking properly at all by the looks of it xD